# Do I have to maintain two versions of website when I want to use AMPed version on mobile?

Tags: html, amp-html

Consider that I have a website with some subpages that I want to accelerate on mobile using AMP.

Do I have to maintain two versions of this subpages one with AMP e.g. using amp-img and one without (with img)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, note that some of the features of non-AMP HTML won't run on AMP pages like 3rd party Javascript. So on your AMP pages, you'll be [doing validations](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/validate). You also need to know how to [link your non-AMP to your AMP pages](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/discovery).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is what has been happening so far for most of the AMP pages, but this is not a strictly requirement.
There are some websites, like https://ampbyexample.com/ which do not have the equivalent not AMP version.

Find some more context [here](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/discovery)