# Downsides of using only AMPed version on website?

Tags: html, amp-html

I recently asked this question:
[Do I have to maintain two versions of website when I want to use AMPed version on mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769648/do-i-have-to-maintain-two-versions-of-website-when-i-want-to-use-amped-version-o)

I'm curious, what if I'd have only AMPed version of website for mobile and desktop? Do you know any downsides of this kind of solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't read any downsides of using only AMPed version on websites. As @noogui stated on your previous question, you'll just only need to maintain the two versions if you think that some of your features like third-party JS will not run. Many web pages were migrating to AMP because of the benefits like [Faster loading page for mobile users](https://www.digivate.com/blog/seo/benefits-of-accelerated-mobile-pages/). You can see more information on this [FAQs page](https://www.ampproject.org/support/faqs/). You can also check with this [Pros and Cons of Google Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP)](https://www.appticles.com/blog/2016/07/debating-the-pros-and-cons-of-google-accelerated-mobile-pages-amp/) blog.